# SQL aggregate function average

Tags: sql

I am a beginner to SQL, trying to find the difference between average price of a cd made by "Skillet" artist with the average price of all cds in a database

E.g. if average of skillet cds = £6, and average price of all cds = £8 then there is a £2 gap (absolute value)

so something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(cdPrice) FROM cd
```

subtract

```
SELECT AVG(cdPrice)
FROM cd, artist
WHERE artName = "Skillet" AND artist.artID = cd.artID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for something like:
`SELECT AVG(cdPrice)-(SELECT AVG(cdPrice) FROM cd JOIN artist ON artist.artID = cd.artID WHERE artName = "Skillet") FROM cd;`

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.avg_overall - y.avg_skillet as net_avg
  from (select avg(cdprice) as avg_overall from cd) x
 cross join (select avg(cdprice) as avg_skillet
               from cd
               join artist
              using (artid)
              where artname = 'Skillet') y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no need for subqueries or cross joins or anything else.

```
select sum(case when a.name = 'skillet' then c.cdprice else 0 end) / sum(case when a.name = 'skillet' then 1 else 0 end) skillet_average, 
  avg(c.cdprice) cd_avg, 
  abs((sum(case when a.name = 'skillet' then c.cdprice else 0 end) / sum(case when a.name = 'skillet' then 1 else 0 end)) - avg(c.cdprice)) diff 
  from cds c
    inner join artist a
    on c.artist_id = a.id;
```

demo fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e29a0/3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is only one artist per CD, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(cdPrice) - AVG(CASE WHEN artName = 'Skillet' THEN cdPrice END)
FROM cd LEFT JOIN
     artist
     ON artist.artID = cd.artID;
```

Two notes:

- Always use single quotes for string and date constants, in preference to double quotes (single quotes are the SQL standard).
- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN`/`ON` syntax.